Generators and Lorentz transformations (LT)
I have been trying to understand how $SO^+(1,3)$ generators are related to LT elements.
I am confused as I don't know how many types of generators are considered.
If we consider the following expression (1):
$(L^{\mu\nu})^\rho_{\ \ \sigma}=i(g^{\mu\rho}g^\nu_{\ \ \sigma}-g^{\nu\rho}g^\mu_{\ \ \sigma})$.
I am attempting to rewrite the angular momentum operators $L_i$ and boost operators $K_i$ in terms of the generators $(L^{\mu\nu})$ by using (1).
I don't understand the distinction between generators of Lorentz group, generators of rotation and translation and Lorentz transformations.
Edit:
Are the expressions  angular momentum/boost operator another way of referring to Lorentz transformations?

Your expression (1) is one particular representation of the Lorentz generators, namely, the vector representation. They can be recast in a plethora of other representations (as tensor and spinor representations). Your question, however (decomposing $L_{\mu\nu}$ into rotations and boosts) is representation independent. Rotations are the $L_{ij}$ where $i,j=1,2,3$ and these can be recast in the more familiar $J_i$ by means of $L_{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}J^k$. Secondly, the boosts are $K_i = L_{0i}$.

@Gold But in your answer, where did you use the expression (1), to generate something?

Expression (1) is not used to extract $J_i$ and $K_i$ from $L_{\mu\nu}$, the equations extracting rotations and boosts are valid in all representations. If you want to write down $J_i$ and $K_i$ in the particular vector representation then you can use (1). For example $K_i$ will be the matrix $(L_{0i})^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}$.

Angular momentum operators and boost operators are not Lorentz transformations but they are generators of Lorentz transformations; you get a Lorentz transformation by exponentiating them.  The six total Lorentz transformation generators are the three angular momentum operators and the three boost operators.
Translation operators are not related to Lorentz transformations, but they are related to Poincare transformations.  The generators of a Poincare transformation are the translation operators plus the six generators of Lorentz transformations.
The angular momentum operators are given by $L_1$ = $L^{23}$, $L_2 = L^{31}$, $L_3 = L^{12}$; the boost operators are given by $K_i = L^{0i}$.

Than if the angular momenta operators and boost operators are generators of lorentz transformations, what are $L^{\mu\nu}}$? Because I cannot see how the expression (1) can give me these generators. Essentially I need to express a group of generators as function of another generator, right?

@imbAF I edited the answer to include more information.

And how can you justify your claim that e.g $L_1=L^{23}$ ?
